# error: Exception Exception in module c:\process\ XXXX.exe at 00017D6B Decompression Error

Tags: windows

For some reason as soon as I login into my PC, I get this error in Windows 7 Ultimate:

http://i51.tinypic.com/b9go6g.png

Any ideas how to get rid of this error and why is it poppoing up?

Answer (score 0):

Find where this application came from (looking at the contents of files in `c:\process` and in the `control panel` will help, if not, you can search for that `XXXX` thing in the `registry` using `regedit`).

Then repair or reinstall it. Or uninstall it completely.

Or, if you're brave enough, debug it. For that you should start looking at the contents of the `Windows event log` and what `Process Monitor`(separate, downloadable tool) shows -- see what errors you get there for this process, they may give you some clues. Finally, you may even run it under a debugger (e.g. `WinDbg`, also separate from Windows and downloadable).